# Having Error message while using the "sudo nautilus" command in terminal

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32 bit). When I run "sudo nautilus" command in the Terminal, this output appears:

```
tushar@tushar-G41M-Combo:~$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for tushar:
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare'     returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory   /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

But still I can edit the folders and files in the "File System". After closing the window this output appears in the terminal:

```
tushar@tushar-G41M-Combo:~$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for tushar:
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

Shutting down nautilus-gdu extension
tushar@tushar-G41M-Combo:~$
```

What is the reason for this error message ? Why with "Failed" and "error" ? How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

`gksu nautilus` would be a better way to open a gui like nautilus from the command line.

Give that a try!

Comment: It doesn't seem like this question is addressing the actual issue. I have this very same error without even opening nautilus on the command line. Also the error message clearly indicates that there is a directory missing.